# Jupyter Notebook/Lab don't launch after I changed the python 32 to 64 bits

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I using Windows 10!

After I removed the Python 3.7 32 bit and installed the 3.7.5 64 bit, the Jupyter Notebook and Lab stop work. (Anaconda doesn't work in my computer... the Qt issue, unsolved! So I use pip to install or remove the packages)

After I remove using the Program Manager, the python directory was still there. Then I changed the directory name and started all over again (removing and installing).

This time, the Jupyter Notebook comes back to live :-), but when I try to launch the Lab, I got this :-/

What can I do?

```
c:\Python>jupyter lab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python\Scripts\jupyter.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 247, in main
    command = _jupyter_abspath(subcommand)
  File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\command.py", line 134, in _jupyter_abspath
    'Jupyter command `{}` not found.'.format(jupyter_subcommand)
Exception: Jupyter command `jupyter-lab` not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installations like this it may be safer to uninstall and reinstall Jupyter rather than redirecting, it will save you a lot of headaches. The following way removes dependencies for a cleaner uninstall, then reinstall.

```
$ pip install pip-autoremove
$ pip-autoremove jupyter -y
$ pip install jupyter
```

(or if you have Python 2 and 3)

```
$ python3 -m pip install jupyter
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Great! Jupyter Lab back to life! Thanks!

Comment: @CarlosAugustoFranaSchettini great! mind marking the answer as correct? Thanks!